# placing an image inside the panel

Tags: asp.net

I have an image like a cloud shape I am placing it as background for the panel. the displays. But as I have specified the height and width here the images displays outside the image there is white space around the image which make the user looks that images is placed inside the panel. so is there any way I want the background image only to come.

```
.modalPopup
{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
}

<asp:Panel ID="pnlHead" runat="server"
    Style="display: none;"
    BackImageUrl="~/WebSiteContent/Images/Cloudd.JPG"
    CssClass="modalPopupWD">
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBody" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Please spell check you question and clarify, it's currently hard to understand what is being asked.

Comment: what Charles said and perhaps include a screenshot. A picture can be worth a thousand words ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried CSS `{ background-color: Transparent; }` so...

```
.modalPopup {
width:600px; height:400px;
background-color: Transparent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think he wants to use transparent image as background but since his image is not transparent (.png), the background is visible there.

Now you can do following :
Create a transparent image which has height and width of panel and make the back ground color of panel to match the background of its container ( Page ).

note : As olle said in the comment its better for you to upload an image showing your problem.